# VOIP with Skype API?

Tags: python, voip, skype, skype4py

I have a robot connected to the internet and I would like to use it to call or receive calls, but I don't know what to implement/develop.

I would like some pieces of advice.

I don't want to pay for this service.

I thought of using Skype4Py but apparently it requires an old version of Skype and I don't know how I could install that on the robot. Plus Microsoft seems to block the usage of the API.

I didn't find any equivalent for Hangout or any other famous communication system. (But I may have missed some. If you know one that I could use, tell me!).

I also looked for Skype bots but it seems that it doesn't do what I expect.

I finally looked for libraries like http://most-voip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_docs/index.html but that doesn't seem like a very practical option. What do you think?

Thank you very much. I would love to hear how you would do.

PS: I would like to use Python as much as possible.